# What are some good examples of announcing new features within a mobile app?

Tags: mobile, design

I'm designing a new feature for my company's mobile app, and I want to make a splash with a brief announcement explaining what the feature is and how to use it. This announcement would appear in the app after the user downloads the update.

Are there relevant apps out that I could look to for inspiration?

Comment: will you have a "what's new" or similar message on google play or appstore?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://inspired-ui.com/tagged/walkthroughs

These are mostly showing first-time-use scenarios, but the same idea can be extended for new features.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to introduce new features to users in mobile app is to use instructional overlays or coach marks (a transparent overlay of UI hints).

[image]

Take a look at this article to see some helpful guidelines on how to implement these UI hints:

http://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-instructional-overlay/

Comment: This isn't really ideal because users won't be able to remember all of those tips since it was all introduced to them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the approach [Slack](https://slack.com) has taken with "hot spots" showing up as you start using the app. While it's annoying after you've been through it a couple of times (joining a new team site triggers the walkthrough for each specific team), it's very effective with how it introduces the functionality.